# call dropdownlist selected index changed event manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdown which fill on page load event.

```
private void FillSponsor()
    {
        ddlSponsor.DataSource = Db.VCT_SPONSORs.Where(x => x.IS_ACTIVE.GetValueOrDefault() && x.IS_APPROVED.GetValueOrDefault());
        ddlSponsor.DataBind();
    }
```

Now what i want is to bind other dropdown with the first value of above dropdown. my second dropdown is:

```
protected void ddlSponsor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlDivision.DataSource = Db.VCT_SPONSOR_DIVISIONs.Where(x => x.SPONSOR_ID==SponsorID);
        ddlDivision.DataBind();
        ddlDivision.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
    }
```

My problem is how to call ddlSponsor_SelectedIndexChanged event  from the FillSponsor method. My both dropdowns are in update panels.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you mean how would you call the method?

```
ddlSponsor_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateBound Event instead. like...

```
protected void ddlSponsor_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlDivision.DataSource = Db.VCT_SPONSOR_DIVISIONs.Where(x => x.SPONSOR_ID==SponsorID);
    ddlDivision.DataBind();
    ddlDivision.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your main problem is having controls in separate update panels.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1426233.aspx

Code sample from that link:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID='asdsd' UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
    ...DropDownList1...
</ContentTemplate>

<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='DropDownList2' EventName='SelectedIndexChanged' />
</Triggers>
```

I believe what you are after is AsyncPostBackTriggers, and don't forget UpdateMode="Conditional".